# What is wrong with this OAuth header?

Tags: oauth, netsuite

This is the OAuth header I have generated using OAuth1.0 Library. Given below .

```
 {"Authorization":"OAuth realm=\"TSTDRV1606019\",oauth_consumer_key=\"c85f08d536fb43ffbf199896b970af6cc8ae3b9ffbd4d5a8d7bd35c36bbc58be\",oauth_nonce=\"PxTkoW9AHGgo36obe2qL\",oauth_signature=\"60eebfff6843f7fb652f98ce6dd65fe025d9837e\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"1497605488\",oauth_version=\"1.0\"","content-type":"application/json"}
```

I keep getting a USER_ ERROR like below

```
 "error" : {"code" : "INVALID_REQUEST", "message" : "The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax."}}
```

Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong ?

Appreciate all the help !

Answer (score 10):

AS of Netsuite release 2021.2, the TBA(Token Based Authentication) with HMAC-SHA1 signature method gets deprecated.  And users who actively use HMAC-SHA1 have to switch to HMAC-SHA256.  Otherwise, the user may find the below error with 4xx error code

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "INVALID_REQUEST",
    "message": "The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax."
  }
}
```

Comment: This was the problem for me too. After changing to SHA256 it was working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the *only* problem, but it looks like you're missing your `oauth_token`. See [Required Data for Using TBA with RESTlets](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/50999/related/1)

Comment: I read on SuiteAnswers that the possible reasons for the error I am seeing  could be due to the timestamp or signature method being rejected.                 Also , I modified my header to include the token as per the article , still no dice

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue why, but after fixing the SHA to 256 I was still getting the *malformed syntax* error when calling from Postman until I set the Advanced -> Version to "1.0" (NOT "1").

[image: Authorization -> Advanced -> Version]